# how to replace new line to empty space on coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset str ="hai how are you? i am fine
what about you?" >
<cfdump var="#str#" /><br>
<cfset str = #replace(str,"#chr(13)&chr(10)#"," ","all")#>
<cfdump var="#str#" /><br>
<cfset str = #reReplace(str, "#chr(13)&chr(10)#"," ")#>
<cfdump var="#str#" />
</cfoutput>
```

Above code produce the this kind of output

```
hai how are you? i am fine what about you?
hai how are you? i am fine what about you?
hai how are you? i am fine what about you?
```

my task is replace the new line character but i can't. if any way to do that please let me know?

Comment: is it possible that instead of `#chr(13) & chr(10)#` that your string has *only* the newline (chr10) *or* the carriage return (chr13) present?  Try replacing both of them individually. `<cfset str = replace(str, chr(13), "", "all")><cfset str = replace(str, chr(10), "", "all")>`

Comment: I can't get the issue. Could you please clarify, what output you are expecting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can understand your issue but we cannot produce a newline character by cfset. And **#chr(13) & chr(10)#** is not valid. it should be either chr(13) or chr(10). You can do two replaces one by one. And **ReReplace** function is used to replace string based on a RegEx. You can use replaceNoCase here. Here is my sample code.

```
  <cfif isDefined("form.submit")>
    <cfset str =form.TestField>
    <cfoutput>
        #findNoCase(Chr(13), str)# <!--- It is available --->
        <cfset str = replaceNoCase(str, chr(13), ' ','All')>
        <cfset str = replaceNoCase(str, chr(10), ' ','All')>
        <cfdump var="#str#"><!--- string after replacement --->
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
<form name="test" method="post">
    <textarea name="TestField"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: <form name="test" method="post">
     <textarea name="TestField"></textarea>
     <input type="submit"name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
<cfif isDefined("form.submit")>
 <cfset str =form.TestField>
 <cfif listlen(str,"#chr(13)#") gt 1>
  <cfset test = " ">
  <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#listlen(str,"#chr(13)#")#">
   <cfset test = listAppend(test,listGetAt(str, i, "#chr(13)#")," ")>
  </cfloop>
 </cfif>
 <cfdump var="#test#" /><br>
 
</cfif>
    <cfoutput>

Comment: If your not used text area in your code maybe my answer is used for you